# How to manage Login Validation with Room in Kotlin?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, authentication, android-room

I'm trying to make work the Login Validation form, but the program stops then reaches the second **if**, and I have *Invalid email* output. Run is clear and out of mistakes. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and why **emailList** is **null**

```
    private fun logIn() {
    val email = binding.editEmailAddress.text.toString()
    val password = binding.editPassword.text.toString()
    if (inputCheck(email, password)) {
        mLoginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[LoginViewModel::class.java]
        val emailList = mLoginViewModel.getUserEmail(email)
        if (emailList != null) {
            if (emailList.password == password) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Logged in as $email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_listFragment)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Invalid email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Fill out blank fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

private fun inputCheck(email: String, password: String): Boolean {
    return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
}
```

LoginViewModel

```
    fun getUserEmail(email: String): User? {
    var checker: User? = null
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        checker = repository.getUserEmail(email)
    }
    return checker
}
```

Comment: in your getUserEmail method, you are always getting null right? this is because you haven't managed thread properly. make getUserEmail function suspended and then call it from activity or Fragment with scope

Comment: exactly, give it a try

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I used a viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) before emailList initialization. but the login doesn't work anyway. IO and Default Dispatchers crash the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun getUserEmail(email: String): User? {
    var checker: User? = null
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        checker = repository.getUserEmail(email)
    }
    return checker 
    // Will return null always because this is not waiting to assign value by above repository method
}
```

Insted you can do this

```
suspend fun getUserEmail(email: String): User? {
    return repository.getUserEmail(email)
}
```

And in Activity Or Fragment

```
mLoginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[LoginViewModel::class.java]
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val emailList = mLoginViewModel.getUserEmail(email)
}
```

Don't Know what error you are getting on above code if that not works then use below code

```
mLoginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[LoginViewModel::class.java]
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val emailList = mLoginViewModel.getUserEmail(email)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            //Do whatever with emailList
        }
    }
```

Comment: Man, Thanks a lot, you solved the issue! I'm new to Kotlin and you improved my understanding. Thank you! May I ask why shouldn't I specify Dispatchers?